# Removing odd occurence value from an array

Tags: java

[https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingCP6965-NRG/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebnYf.png)

```
import java.util.*;

    class Solution {
          public int solution(int[] A) {

            ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++){
                B.add(A[i]);
            }

            while(B.size() != 1){

                for(int j = 1; j <B.size();j++){

                    if(B.get(0) == B.get(j)){
                        B.remove(j);
                        B.remove(0);
                        break;
                    }

                    if(j == B.size()-1 && B.get(0) != B.get(j)){
                        return B.get(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            return B.get(0);
        }
    }
```

I can pass until the Correctness tests where n=601. 
but i can't pass on the Performance tests because of wrong answer.
So i want to know why my code is wrong.
https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected vs. actual outcome and why would that outcome be expected? Have you debugged your code? (I will not visit an external link to understand your problem)

Comment: i can't get the sample of inputs because they are in inside of CODILITY site!

Comment: the site of CODILITY give me just the result of my code T.T So, i cant debug. if i could debug i wouldn't use stack overflow!

Comment: i add the picture of  the result of my code at first line! i couldn't upload just image file so i have recomended to upload the image file for link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's running time is `O(n^2)` due to the nested loops, so it's too slow for large inputs.

On each iteration of your outer loop you detect and eliminate a single pair of equal elements. This means there would be (n-1)/2 iterations of that loop.

Your inner loop may iterate over all the remaining elements of the array in each iteration, so at the worst case, the first execution of the inner loop will have n iterations, the second will have n-2 iterations, and so on.

Therefore, the total running time is bound by

```
n + n - 2 + n - 4 + ... + 3 = (n + 3)*(n - 1)/4 = O(n^2)
```

I suggest you use a `HashSet<Integer>` to store the elements you encounter if not present, and remove them if they are present. This will take linear time (`O(n)`).

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if (!set.add(A[i])) { // add will return false if A[i] is already in the Set,
                                 // in which case we know we found a pair of equal numbers,
                                 // so we remove that number
                set.remove(A[i]);
            }
        }
        return set.iterator().next(); // according to the problem description, there should 
                                      // be exactly one element left
    }
}
```

Comment: missing `)` over here (!set.add(A[i])

Comment: Thx!! i will use this code and report you the result

Comment: Yes you got a perfect score!! but i want to know where and why my code is wrong

Comment: @Eran yes i exactly understood your code! and very feeling thx to you! 
So im believing that there is no wrong code in my code but just low performance
it that right?

Comment: @Eran THX! i appreciate you really so much! i saw your code for the first time until now.
i can learn new skill and i can solve another problem with your skill! thx!

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution is to use **Bitwise XOR(^)** :

```java
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            result = result ^ A[i];
        }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! i could understand your code! if the same number is excuted Bitwise XOR the result become 0. So lastly the number that has no pair will be remained! is  that correct? it was very helpful to study the world of coding!

Comment: @신상택 Yes you are absolutely correct and this will be the fastest solution for your problem.